# How to change font for UTF-8 encoded pages in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In Internet Options dialog I can set font for various "Language scripts" (read: encodings), but there is no option to set font for UTF-8 encoded pages, and for such pages Internet Explorer renders some awful font for unknown reason to me.

How can I set font for UTF-8 encoded pages in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: Language scripts itself gets encoded using UTF-8(1 of the encoding schemes). You look confused or I am confused about your Q. `Language scripts` option in `IE` itself is for the webpages which don't have fonts specified.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, as IE is not my browser although while running Windows using it is inevitable. If I load a page with set UTF-8 encoding in header, IE renders page awfully as reported. Then if I right-click on such page and from context menu change encoding from UTF-8 to some other (which I can set in "Internet Options > Fonts") page is rendered fine (with font that I set for other encoding).

Comment: For example, here is how Wikipedia is rendered: http://i.imgur.com/L9YTcBX.png Only pages set to UTF-8 encoding are rendered like that, with that font

Answer (score 1):

***Following*** on from the comment:

There are 2 things happening here:

1. *Encoding* of the page in `UTF-8` to support multi-byte characters(non-English letters) display.
2. `Fonts` trying to be applied to these UNICODE characters.

Now, issue is with **#2**. All the fonts don't support all unicode characters. **For ex:** If the webpage is displaying *Simplified Chinese* and the *font* set in the browser don't support the script, your webpage will look weird.

One solutions to this is to set font which supports most of unicode characters. **For ex:** *Arial Unicode MS*. This font supports most of the unicode characters.

***Moral of the story,*** you need to take care of 2 things while displaying unicode characters,

1. Proper supporting encoding scheme. **ie:** UTF-8
2. Fonts which support these UNICODE characters.

Comment: All right, so my question is how can I set the font for UTF-8 encoded pages? I can't find such setting in Internet Options.

Comment: First check if the encoding selected is UTF-8. Open IE >> View >> Encoding >> UTF-8

Comment: I already commented in my first comment, that encoding is UTF-8 when I right click on a page.

Comment: If you are sure it is already UTF-8 then IE will pick up the fonts on its own. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But it is a problem as you can see from the screenshot in my second comment. That's why I asked this question - how to change font for UTF-8 encoded pages in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: No, you don't set generic UTF-8 font in IE. You can set font for individual script. There was misunderstanding because of how the Q was formulated :)

Comment: The wikipage already sets the appropriate font when it is being processed in its application server. It is then served to your browser.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not just Wikipedia. Any page with encoding set to UTF-8 is rendered like that.

Comment: LOL ! I was talking about font being set by the app server in the webpage before being served to browser. Which is why they are rendered in a particular way.